# atos failed to read xx.dSYM: The file “DWARF” couldn’t be opened

Tags: ios, dsym, ips

I have a crash report from MyApp,so I have a dSYM file. I have run the following code:
atos -arch arm64 -o MyApp.app.dSYM -l 0x104148000 0x00000001080031fc
However, instead of getting the proper output, I am receiving an error:

atos failed to read MyApp.app.dSYM: The file “DWARF” couldn’t be opened.
Any suggestions as to why this might be happening? I am not stripping debug symbols from the app.

Comment: Check permissions and maybe check if the dwarf symbols in the .dSYM are dwarf 5. You may need to update stuff if it's dwarf 5.